# Implement state eraser for NIST DRBG and other crypto primitives using macro

Tags: c, cryptography, type-safety

As a spare-time personal project, I'm implementing a set of symmetric-key cryptographic primitives.

One thing I've left vacant for a long time, is the key/state eraser, which I decide to add right now.

I intend it to be a macro, so that it doesn't require any additional object file; the macro should be statement-like (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154136/6230282)), so that its usage is consistent with those from other lines.

Here's my current code:

```c
#define ERASE_STATES(buf, len)                  \
    do {                                        \
        for(uintptr_t i=0; i<len; i++)          \
            ((char *)buf)[i] = 0;               \
    } while(0)
```

There's a few things I'm not entirely confident about.

1. `len` is a cardinal and it'd probably be a `size_t`, but `i` is an ordinal, should I also use `size_t`, or change it to some other type for semantic consistency? (I'm using `uintptr_t` right now.)
2. The signedness of the type `char` is explicitly undefined according to standard, but could it nontheless be used without sacrificing semantic consistency, as a generic type representing a byte when assigning non-negative values to it?
3. Anything else I've missed?

**Update**

I'm not using `memset` because I designed my code to be compilable in free-standing environment.

Comment: Doing things you know are *undefined* behaviour and expecting *defined* behaviour isn't going to work. What is your concern in this regard? Have you tested the current code in multiple situations and does it appear to function correctly?

Comment: @Mast I assume you mean my Q2, as it's the only Q with the word "undefined" in it. My concern is that (assuming I've casted type correctly) the content of `buf` would end up with non-zero bits, or observable gap didn't get re-initialized.

Comment: @Mast, I've tested the code on my 64-bit macOS Catalina, but I don't currently have a big-endian or 32-bit environment available to me right now.

Comment: What's with the loop? A plain old braced block is entirely valid C.

Comment: @Reinderien As mentioned in the OP, "per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154136/6230282)".

Answer (score 2):

There is not much code so I won't write much review

The issue that makes me most uneasy is the interface decision, specifically requiring calling code to calculate len in bytes.

If I am in "trying my best mode" as a coder, late at night with a stressful customer deadline hanging over me, it'll be all I can manage to remember to clear memory. I will inevitably try to clear an int array of 8 elements with `ERASE_STATE(arr, 8)`. If I am lucky I will remember to use 32 and add a comment about the 4x8 calculation. I am unlikely to remember to account for the fact that other architectures could have a 16 or 64 bit int.

I would very much prefer a macro that took care of the type sizes for me and left the interface as passing the the natural array size.

Answer (score 1):

## Q1

`uintptr_t` is used for representing pointers numerically, so it's not suitable even if the underlying representation is identical to that of `size_t`, the same can be said for `ptrdiff_t`.

On the other hand, it's common knowledge that the set of finite ordinals is isomorphic to the set of finite cardinals, so `size_t` can be your friend here. What's more, the loop condition may be improved by adding a cast to `size_t` to `len` to ensure the loop always ends even when the original type of `len` has greater width than `size_t` although one should always ensure `len` has a sane value. Also, the cast would be necessarily present had you actually implement `ERASE_STATES` as a function.

So use `size_t`.

## Q2

If you're really concerned that assigning the literal `0` to a `char` would get you a "negative zero" in one's complement or signed magnitude representation, then use `unsigned char` (which is just the same intermediate type used when the standard defined `memset`). Otherwise, the a world proliferous of two's complement signed integers, a plain `char` offers better clarity when the value is non-negative.

Also, there's guarantee that `char[]` is gap-free (unlike `uint8_t`).

## Q3

Since it's a macro and not a function, `buf` and `len` will be evaluated multiple times during the loop. This limits its usage to lvalues and constant expressions.

Unless you assign arguments to temporary variables.

## Improved Code

```c
#define ERASE_STATES(buf, len)          \
    do {                                \
        char *ba = (void *)buf;         \
        size_t l = (size_t)len;         \
        for(size_t i=0; i<l; i++)       \
            ba[i] = 0;                  \
    } while(0)
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to this. In the improved code, is the compiler guaranteed to spot that the cast of len to size_t only has to happen once? Or will this spend half its time casting for the check?

Comment: @Josiah, good point, changed answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much to review here, since it's only a single macro, but there's still room for improvement.

### Don't use a macro

> I intend it to be a macro, so that it doesn't require any additional object file

If that's the motivation for using a macro, it's based on a misconception.  You can get that and avoid the [problems of macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104568/macro-vs-function-in-c), by defining a static function instead.  Consider this code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define ERASE_STATES(buf, len)                  \
    do {                                        \
        for(uintptr_t i=0; i<len; i++)          \
            ((char *)buf)[i] = 0;               \
    } while(0)

unsigned buffer1[11];
unsigned buffer2[13];

static void memclr(void *buf, unsigned len) {
    for (char *b = buf ;len; --len, ++b) {
        *b = 0;
    }
}

void foo1() {
    ERASE_STATES(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1)*sizeof(*buffer1));
}

void foo2() {
    ERASE_STATES(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2)*sizeof(*buffer2));
}

void bar1() {
    memclr(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1)*sizeof(*buffer1));
}

void bar2() {
    memclr(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2)*sizeof(*buffer2));
}

int main() {
    foo1();
    foo2();
    bar1();
    bar2();
}
```

Does a modern compiler generate different code for `foo1` versus `bar1`?  No.  It generates the [exact same code](https://godbolt.org/z/MKg6aQ) without requiring any additional libraries or translation units, and without any runtime overhead for function calls.  It also does not sacrifice type safety and is easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: Isn't it against convention to define functions in header files? Also, what about those "unused static function" warnings in object files that don't use it?

Comment: Don’t put a static function in a header file. If it is needed in multiple C files, duplicate it in multiple C files.